# SASS: Using the parent reference (&) inside and @if ... @else structure. & picks up else instead of parent

Tags: css, if-statement, sass, parent

I'm using the &: select inside a SASS @if block inside a mixin.

```
@mixin mixin-name {
   @if (condition) {
        .....
   } else {
        &:nth-of-type(...) {}
   }
}
```

The &:Nth-of-type is the outermost actual selector inside the mixin. In my code, I use it this way:

```
aside {
    @include mixin-name;
}
```

I'm expecting this in the CSS output:

```
aside:nth-of-type() {}
```

Instead, I get this:

```
aside else:nth-of-type() {}
```

Clearly SASS is picking up the **else** as the "parent" instead of the aside. The old mixin included the aside element within the mixin, but I wanted to make it more flexible, to use it with any selector.

My current solution is to pass the selector into the mixin as variable and use it this way:

```
#{$var} {
    &:nth-of-type() {}
}
```

This works, but it seems like a bug that the **&** should pick up a piece of code instead of the actual selector. Anyone have a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `@else`.  You can check the full documentation here: [SASS Docs](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#_8)

Basically, SASS is thinking that `else` is a CSS keyword/identifier. It needs to be prefixed with the `@`.

Ie, your code would become:

```
@mixin mixin-name {
   @if (condition) {
        .....
   } @else {
        &:nth-of-type(...) {}
   }
}
```

Comment: You're right. And the dumb thing is, I did it right the first time (the earlier mixin), but slipped up the second... Thanks.

Comment: No problems, @Paul, if my answer helped you, could you please tick my answer as the correct one? It will give you a better stance when asking future questions.